# How can I repeat a task in java/android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, string

I want to complete a task, which assigns the variable `randomButton` a value. At the end, I want to check the value of `randomButton` If it is something I don't like, I want to re do the task where I assign `randomButton` a value.

I want to do this task:

```
        int i = rng.nextInt(4); //Find random button from between 1-4
        randomButton = buttons.get(i);
        buttonBackground = randomButton.getBackground();
        Log.v(TAG, "In the do");
```

and if

```
buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle)
```

I want to try and do the task again. How do I achieve this...?

I have tried:

```
do {
            int i = rng.nextInt(4); //Find random button from between 1-4
            randomButton = buttons.get(i);
            buttonBackground = randomButton.getBackground();
            Log.v(TAG, "In the do");
        }while(!buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle));
```

But that is an infinite loop. So how do I repeat a task if the value is something I don't like?

By the way, `buttons` is an arraylist with different image button objects.  I want to see if the background of that imagebutton (randomButton) is redcircle. If it is, I want to go through the code again. If it isn't, thats great, and I can continue.

Comment: set the while to correct value (something that you don t like) and be sure that sometimes it can be something you like, hence now its never a R.drawable.redcircle

Comment: I think your problem lies in `buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle)`. `R.drawable.redcircle` is an `int`. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes, I am sure that buttonBackground can equal something other then the drawable redcircle. My arraylist of buttons `buttons` contains four buttons with different drawables...So it is sometimes redcircle...

Comment: You have ! before so it needs to be the int value of R.drawable.redcircle

Comment: @PetterFriberg Oh. I just wanted to check whether the background image is redcircle or not. Thats why I put !. To say not equal. What should I do instead?

Comment: @m0skit0 I want to see if the background of that imagebutton (randomButton) is redcircle. If it is, I want to go through the code again. If it isn't, thats great, and I can continue.

Comment: Remove the !... System.out.println the stuff that i need to know what is it....

Comment: @PetterFriberg Well this is android, so I can't System.out.println, but I can log it. But, I'm trying to see  if the background of that imagebutton (randomButton) is redcircle. If it is, I want to go through the code again. If it isn't, thats great, and I can continue

Comment: What class is buttonBackground?, what class is R.drawable.redcircle?

Comment: @PetterFriberg redcircle is an image stored in my drawable directory. ButtonBackground is the background of the random button which I pick out from my `buttons` array list

Comment: You should surely remove the NOT ! and then you need to figure out how you can determine if the background has the redcirlce image (log some), I don't think the current compare will work

Answer (score 0):

A do-while loop would be the correct way to to this. I do not know what R.drawable.redcircle means, is that a color?

You did something wrong in the while clause:

```
}while(!buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle));
```

I should have posted this in the comment but i couldn't since i dont have 50 reputation yet.

Comment: For clarification: Everything in `R.drawable` is an Object of type `Drawable`. It can be anything like color, image, vector graphic, gradient or simply anything you can *draw* on the screen of a device.